# Find the minimum value of $P=\frac{\sqrt{3(2x^2+2x+1)}}{3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+(3-\sqrt{3})x+3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+(3+\sqrt{3})x+3}}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization

Let $x$ be a real number. Find the minimum value of

$$P=\frac{\sqrt{3(2x^2+2x+1)}}{3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+(3-\sqrt{3})x+3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+(3+\sqrt{3})x+3}}$$

This is a problem from 2015 Vietnamese University Entrance Exam.

I tried plotting and finding all local minima but that seems to be impossible as the derivative is too complicated. I guess this problem can only be solved by using inequalities.